# How to find the screen size of two monitors using wx.displaySize()

Tags: python, wxpython, multiple-monitors

I want to get the screen size for two monitors using wxPython.

To get the screen size of one monitor: (screenSize is [] containing x and y value).

```
screenSize = wx.DisplaySize()
```

but I want something that will work for multiple monitors like the following:

```
screenSizeMonitor1 = wx.DisplaySize()
screenSizeMonitor2 = wx.DisplaySize()
```

If possible, it would be nice to know which monitor is on the left (if using two monitors) and which is on the right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [GetGeometry()](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Display-class.html#GetGeometry) method of the [wx.Display](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Display-class.html) class:

```
displays = (wx.Display(i) for i in range(wx.Display.GetCount()))
sizes = [display.GetGeometry().GetSize() for display in displays]
```

To determine the leftmost monitor, you only have to compare the left coordinates of the `wx.Rect` instances returned by `GetGeometry()`. The monitor with the smallest left coordinate is the leftmost one.